# Como usar um banco de dados pronto no Android com SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que faz download de um banco de dados de acordo com o estado (UF) do usuário.  Alguém sabe como faço para inserir os dados no banco de dados?
Obs.: o arquivo de banco de dados, pode chegar há 200 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edgar Muniz Berlinck a classe [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, já fiz algo parecido mas não sei se vai ajudar, mas vamos lá:

**Alimentar o banco de dados manualmente utilizando JSON**
Eu fiz a carga no banco de dados utilizando um serviço. Este serviço retornova um JSON paginado de 1000 em 1000 registros e eu incluia isso no banco de dados.

**Carregar o banco de dados binário em seu app [fonte SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162194/how-to-download-an-sqlite-database-from-an-android-device)**

Você pode usar este método para gravar em seu private storage

```
private static boolean downloadDatabase(Context context) {
            try {
                   // Log.d(TAG, "downloading database");
                    URL url = new URL("http://some-url.com/db/" + "db_name.s3db");
                    /* Open a connection to that URL. */
                    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
                    /*
                     * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                     */
                    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    /*
                     * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                     */
                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                    int current = 0;
                    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                            baf.append((byte) current);
                    }

                    /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    // Select storage location
                    fos = context.openFileOutput("db_name.s3db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

                    fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                    fos.close();
                   // Log.d(TAG, "downloaded");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "downloadDatabase Error: " , e);
                    return false;
            }  catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "downloadDatabase Error: " , e);
                    return false;
            } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "downloadDatabase Error: " , e);
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Pensei em transformar o banco de dados em JSON e inserir com uma activity, mas acho que é muito grande, o aplicativo pode fechar. Não sei, sou novato. Mas se o arquivo demora para abrir no meu computador, imagina processar o texto num smartphone, mas se deu certo para você, deve funcionar. Agora pouco encontrei uma classe que acho que vai resolver o problema. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: @JorgyanRibeiro Se vc transformar o banco em JSON você deve carregar os registros em bloco. Mas logo abaixo tem um exemplo para baixar o banco sqlite para o seu app.